# Is there a faster implementation of uuidgen from bash?

Tags: bash, uuid

I am using a bash script and using the command `uuidgen` to generate UUIDs. However it is quite slow when invoked in a loop. Are there any alternatives I can invoke directly from bash?

I'm guessing the slowness is actually just invoking and stopping the process each loop iteration, not necessary `uuidgen` being slow code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` command uses the kernel UUID generator to generate random UUIDs.

It still has the invocation delay, but the generation itself is likely faster.

Comment: `cat: /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid: No such file or directory`

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: Needs to work across `osx` as well as `debian/ubuntu`.

Comment: OK, this solution only works on Linux. I don't know if MacOS has a similar random generator available.